# Textarea width in horizontal form

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, textarea

I've been trying for hours including provided Bootstrap .css file to make my textareas wider.

I'll have a lot of text in some of them, and they are just to small for me to use them properly.

Please take a look at the screenshot i made :

[image]

This is my code :

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="tld_edit" method="post" action="">
   <div class="form-group">
    <label for="PrimaryInternalNote" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
      <strong><?php echo SYSTEM::Com(389); ?></strong>
    </label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
     <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" 
       placeholder="<?php echo SYSTEM::Com(395); ?>" 
       id="PrimaryInternalNote" name="PrimaryInternalNote">
     <?php echo $row['PrimaryInternalNote']; ?>
     </textarea>
    </div>
 </div>    
</form>
```

This is what I use for each input in this form. I would like to make it 2-3 times wider, up to the width of

```
<div class="container">
```

in which all the data is put in.

Any ideas on how to do this ?

Comment: Rename `class` for `textarea` and give it width & height like `.custom-textarea { width: 600px; max-width: 700px; min-height: 200px; }`

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
<textarea cols="40" rows="10"></textarea>
         //missing
```